# How to colour background sections of graphs in R to indicate time periods of interest

Tags: r, graph, colors, linegraph

I would like to add colour 'chunks' to the background of my graphs in R to highlight nesting periods. My x axis is in days, so I'd like the colours to be set 'from-to' certain days.
I've created a crude manual version of how I'd like it to look on my graph (see image) but am unsure how to implement this within my code. I'd ideally like to have different colours for different chunks e.g. orange for one period and blue for another period of interest which can also be displayed in a legend on the right. My data is distance per day, which was then converted to standard deviations for graphing.

[image]

Code below for distance to stdev, then graphing using the standard plot() function:

```
ig16 <- read.csv(file='ig16distance.csv')
ig16$stdDist <- (ig16$Distance - mean(ig16$Distance))/sd(ig16$Distance)
plot(ig16$stdDist, type = "o",col = "red", xlab = "Days", ylab = "Stdev", 
 main = "IG0016")
```

Sample data below:

```
    Day   Distance
1     1  20.396078
2     2  21.540659
3     3   4.000000
4     4  16.492423
5     5  16.000000
6     6  34.000000
7     7  34.234486
8     8   0.000000
9     9   4.000000
10   10   0.000000
11   11   0.000000
12   12   0.000000
13   13   0.000000
14   14  22.203603
15   15   0.000000
16   16   0.000000
17   17   2.280351
18   18   2.280351
19   19   2.280351
20   20   2.280351
```

Any advice on code to achieve this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not provide data, I will illustrate with some simple example data.  You can just plot some transparent rectangles over the region that you want to highlight.

```
kings = c(60, 43, 67, 50, 56, 42, 50, 65, 68, 43, 65, 34, 47, 34, 49, 
41, 13, 35, 53, 56, 16, 43, 69, 59, 48, 59, 86, 55, 68, 51, 33, 
49, 67, 77, 81, 67, 71, 81, 68, 70, 77, 56)

plot(kings, type = "o",col = "red", xlab = "", ylab = "Years", 
 main = "Kings")
polygon(x=c(5,5,15,15), y=c(0,100,100,0), col="#0000FF22", border=F)
polygon(x=c(25,25,35,35), y=c(0,100,100,0), col="#FF990022", border=F)
```

[image: Time series with highlighted periods.]

Comment: Apologies was just adding some sample data to my original post in answer to your first comment. That looks great, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this, a kind of an event plot:

```
kings = c(60, 43, 67, 50, 56, 42, 50, 65, 68, 43, 65, 34, 47, 34, 49, 
          41, 13, 35, 53, 56, 16, 43, 69, 59, 48, 59, 86, 55, 68, 51, 33, 
          49, 67, 77, 81, 67, 71, 81, 68, 70, 77, 56)

plot(kings, ylim=c(-25,100), type = "o",col = "red", xlab = "", ylab = "Years", main = "Kings")
rect(5, -10,15,-20,col=rgb(0,0,1,.133),border=NA)
rect(25,-10,35,-20,col=rgb(1,.6,0,.133),border=NA)
```

[image]